Dynamic parametrized tests with GoogleTest and CTest
I'm trying to make CMake discover tests on the actual invocation, not during the build, using Ninja Multi-Config generator. Initially I thought that setting DISCOVERY_MODE to PRE_TEST in gtest_discover_tests should solve it, but apparently not.
Here's the minimal reproducible example. We need the following files:

CMakeLists.txt
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
 project(dynamic_gtests CXX)

 set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
 set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

 include(FetchContent)
 FetchContent_Declare(
   googletest
   URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/5a37b517ad4ab6738556f0284c256cae1466c5b4.zip
 )
 # For Windows: Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker settings
 set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
 FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

 enable_testing()

 add_executable(mytest test.cpp)
 target_link_libraries(mytest PRIVATE GTest::gtest_main)

 include(GoogleTest)
 gtest_discover_tests(mytest WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} DISCOVERY_MODE PRE_TEST)


test.cpp
 #include <gtest/gtest.h>

 #include <algorithm>
 #include <filesystem>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <tuple>
 #include <vector>

 using Param = std::filesystem::path;

 class ParamTest : public ::testing::TestWithParam<Param>
 {
 };

 TEST_P(ParamTest, Test1)
 {
     std::ifstream file(GetParam());
     int value;
     file >> value;
     EXPECT_EQ(value, 42);
 }

 static std::vector<Param> discover_files()
 {
     std::vector<Param> params;
     std::copy(std::filesystem::directory_iterator("data"),
             std::filesystem::directory_iterator(), std::back_inserter(params));
     return params;
 }

 INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P(ParamTestSuite, ParamTest,
                          ::testing::ValuesIn(discover_files()));


CMakePresets.json
 {
     "version": 3,
     "configurePresets": [
         {
             "name": "default",
             "generator": "Ninja Multi-Config",
             "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/build"
         }
     ],
     "buildPresets": [
         {
             "name": "default",
             "configurePreset": "default",
             "configuration": "Debug"
         }
     ],
     "testPresets": [
         {
             "name": "default",
             "configurePreset": "default",
             "configuration": "Debug"
         }
     ]
 }



Now I'm executing the following commands:
mkdir data
echo 42 > data/answer.txt
cmake --preset default
cmake --build --preset default
ctest --preset default

The test passes successfully. After this, let's create a new data file for this test and try to run it:
echo 43 > data/incorrect.txt
./build/Debug/mytest
cmake --build --preset default
ctest --preset default

Running mytest directly works (it's showing a failing subtest ParamTestSuite/ParamTest.Test1/1), but with CTest, the new test is not discovered and is not executed (only one subtest is being run). Can this be solved?
